# Access a certain property in a large PHP object

Tags: php

I ran a PHP query for my WordPress site with the following code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cases',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    offset => 2
);
$the_query1 = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query1 -> have_posts() ):
    print_r($the_query1);
while ( $the_query1->have_posts() ): $the_query1->the_post();
```

This is the object returned:

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query] => Array
        (
            [post_type] => cases
            [posts_per_page] => 3
            [offset] => 2
        )

    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [post_type] => cases
            [posts_per_page] => 3
            [offset] => 2
            [paged] => 0
            [embed] => 
            [category__in] => Array
                (
                )
            [update_post_term_cache] => 1
            [lazy_load_term_meta] => 1
            [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
            [nopaging] => 
            [comments_per_page] => 50
            [no_found_rows] => 
            [order] => DESC
        )

    [tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
        (
            [queries] => Array
                (
                )

            [relation] => AND

            [primary_table] => wp_posts
            [primary_id_column] => ID
        )

    [request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'cases' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 2, 3
    [posts] => Array
        (
            [0] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 19163
                    [post_author] => 2
                    [post_date] => 2018-09-28 15:42:12
                    [post_content] => 
                    [post_title] => Global Factories
                    [post_modified] => 2018-11-15 12:41:57
                    [post_modified_gmt] => 2018-11-15 11:41:57
                    [post_content_filtered] => 
                    [post_parent] => 0
                    [guid] => https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19163
                    [menu_order] => 0
                    [post_type] => cases
                    [post_mime_type] => 
                    [comment_count] => 0
                    [filter] => raw
                )

            [1] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 19167
                    [post_author] => 2
                    [post_date] => 2018-09-21 14:58:50
                    [post_content] => 
                    [post_title] => Warmteservice Groep B.V.
                    [post_modified] => 2018-11-15 12:00:56
                    [post_modified_gmt] => 2018-11-15 11:00:56
                    [post_content_filtered] => 
                    [post_parent] => 0
                    [guid] => https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19167
                    [menu_order] => 0
                    [post_type] => cases
                    [post_mime_type] => 
                    [comment_count] => 0
                    [filter] => raw
                )

            [2] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 19157
                    [post_author] => 2
                    [post_date] => 2018-09-21 11:26:12
                    [post_content_filtered] => 
                    [post_parent] => 0
                    [guid] => https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19157
                    [menu_order] => 0
                    [post_type] => cases
                    [post_mime_type] => 
                    [comment_count] => 0
                    [filter] => raw
                )

        )

    [post_count] => 3
    [current_comment] => -1
    [found_posts] => 43
    [max_num_pages] => 15
    [max_num_comment_pages] => 0
    [query_vars_hash:WP_Query:private] => 63c13903269b2ec070d244b97926b6e4
    [query_vars_changed:WP_Query:private] => 
    [thumbnails_cached] => 
    [stopwords:WP_Query:private] => 
    [compat_fields:WP_Query:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => query_vars_hash
            [1] => query_vars_changed
        )

)
```

If you look in the middle of the object, there is an object property called [posts] which is an array consisting of three properties. I would like to access this property and then check if the second index ([1]) is true and do something based on that. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to access that property in PHP. Please advise.

Comment: `if(is_array($the_query1->posts[1]) && count($the_query1->posts[1]) > 0 ){...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dumping the object using `print_r()`, I was able to access the `posts` array using:

```
print_r($the_query1 -> posts);
```